# Python. What is the name of this loop

Tags: python, loops

I have some code:

...

```
reader.loop(0, callback)
```

...

(from here http://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/using-impacketpcapy-with-python-2-6-on-windows/)

How this "loop" named and where i can read about it or how to break that "loop" (how it works at all).

Thanx.

Comment: `reader` seems to be an instance of some class provided by `pycap`: http://oss.coresecurity.com/projects/pcapy.html Have a look at its documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`loop` is not a keyword or other special construct in Python.

`reader` simply has a member function called `loop` that takes two parameters. To find out what this `loop` member function does, check what kind of object `reader` is and look for `loop` in that class' documentation.